# Jenkins API - Add credentials

Tags: jenkins

I am adding credentials to my jenkins server via the REST API. When I try to use them it does not work.
When I copy the token-hash from the credentials.xml file and decode it like [here](https://medium.com/@eng.mohamed.m.saeed/show-all-credentials-value-in-jenkins-using-script-console-83784e95b857), I get the token I sent via the API but **with additional spacing before the token and a linebreak afterwards**. How can I remove that?

Saved via the GUI:

```
q4nL6VYHNy7PoyfKGj7z
```

Sent via the api:

```
        q4nL6VYHNy7PoyfKGj7z
```

This is the XML I send to the server

```xml
<io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabserverconfig.credentials.PersonalAccessTokenImpl plugin="gitlab-branch-source@1.5.9">
    <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
    <id>name</id>
    <description>description</description>
    <token>secret-token</token>
</io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabserverconfig.credentials.PersonalAccessTokenImpl>
```